# Filtered rows with formula fill down

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula to fill down into visible rows after filtering. The problem is the function works perfectly if I change the formula to 1+1, but when I change it to the `VLOOKUP` function, it inserts the `VLOOKUP` formula into the Heading and gives me the error "FillDown method of range class failed"

```
Sub GG()
With Sheet1
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$43123").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="#N/A"

With ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
.Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\Users\Reports\[Lookup Data Table.xlsx]Product Group'!A2:L2835,5,FALSE)"
.Cells.FillDown


End With

End With
End Sub
```

If I change the formula in this line to `=1+1` it fills down the visible rows and the heading remains intact.

```
.Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\Users\Reports\[Lookup Data Table.xlsx]Product Group'!A2:L2835,5,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Those nested With statements look a bit "off"

Comment: You are using `R1C1` formula *without actually using R1C1 notation in the formula itself*

Comment: You can use Offset(1,0) to skip header at the end SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0) but did you intend to put the formula in the non visible cells?

Comment: no I only want to put the formula into the visible cell only. and with the offset(1,0), it copies the column heading to e2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering on column E so use that for the visible cells.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

You may wish to use `.Formula` , as noted in comments you are not using R1C1 notation in the formula. Also, you need to fix your lookup range `$A$2:$L$283` unless you want it to shift? And I am not sure you need the `.FillDown` as you are already applying the formula to a range.